# Lua display.newText not showing in scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

```
function scene:create( event )
    print("ifc.scene1 - scene:create() @ " .. getTimer())
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Create a label showing which scene this is
    local label = display.newText( sceneGroup, "Main Menu", centerX, h/6, native.systemFont, 30 )


end
```

I was looking at this sample code from a tutorial and this is just a snip of the code, but everything else works, this part is what basically puts a headline at the top of your screen that should say "Main Menu" but its not showing up does anyone know why?

Comment: Link to the tutorial? Do you use `label` anywhere? Do you need to to make it show up?

Comment: https://github.com/roaminggamer/CoronaGeek/blob/master/Hangouts/composer_scene_manager.zip @EtanReisner i was looking at "good management" folder

Comment: Checked the tutorial and it works for me. Your code should also work. Could you post all of your code?

Comment: @jefecito the code works no problem but I dont see the label that is present. I didnt change anything except for this part of the code function scene:create( event )
 print("ifc.scene1 - scene:create() @ " .. getTimer())
 local sceneGroup = self.view

 -- Create a label showing which scene this is
 local background = display.newRect ( sceneGroup, centerX, centerY, w, h)
 background:setFillColor(.2,1,1)
 local label = display.newText( sceneGroup, "Main Menu", centerX, h/6, native.systemFont, 30 )

Comment: @JohnnyChan the comment contains more code than the on in the OP. Could you edit your OP and add the whole scene (i.e. all the code)?

Comment: What does centerX means ? Where do you define it ?